# Django: How do I position a page when using Django templates

Tags: django

I have a web page where the user enters some data and then clicks a submit button. I process the data and then use the same Django template to display the original data, the submit button, and the results. When I am using the Django template to display results, I would like the page to be automatically scrolled down to the part of the page where the results begin. This allows the user to scroll back up the page if she wants to change her original data and click submit again. Hopefully, there's some simple way of doing this that I can't see at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should already work if you provide a [**fragment identifier**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in the action method of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url#results">
    <!-- ...  -->
</form>
```

and somewhere below the form, where you want to show the results:

```
<div id="results">
    <!-- your results here -->
</div>
```

This should make the page jump to the `<div>` with ID `results`.

It is complete client site and does not involve Django, JavaScript or similar.

Comment: Hi Felix. I am curious what happens if form will not validate in django view. I did not test that but I think page will be scrolled down while there are some errors in the form and there is no data to be displayed. Am I right?

Comment: this worked great. Thanks!
@Dzida I only add the results div if there are some results, so in the case of an error it doesn't scroll.

Comment: @Dzida, @swisstony: Exactly, if there is no element with this ID, nothing happens :)

Comment: OK, right. I thought that you insert data to some place in the page that exists all the time. In this case Felix's solution is more elegant.+1

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your data into something like this:

```
<div id="some-id">YOUR DATA TO BE DISPLAYED</div>
```

and if you make redirect in your view you need to redirect to url: `/some-url/#some-id`

if you don't make redirect you need to scroll to the bottom using javascript (but note that redirect is preffered way to use in view after saving data).