# Django: How to position a page when using Django templates and links

Tags: django

I have this in my template:

```
<div id="comment-{{ post_comment.id }}">
<a title="Comment was useful" href="/useful-comment/{{ blog_post.id }}/{{ post_comment.id }}/">
```

When the user clicks on this link, the method useful_comment(blog_post_id, post_comment_id) is called and at when it returns it loads the same template again. I then want to scroll the page down to #comment-{{ post_comment.id }}, but how do I do that if I load my template like so:

```
arguments = dict(user = request.user, blog_post = blog_post)

t = loader.get_template('blog-post-template.html')
c = RequestContext(request, args)
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

This is related to [Django: How do I position a page when using Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036273/django-how-do-i-position-a-page-when-using-django-templates/3036307#3036307), but in that question they are using forms and only scrolling down to a static section of the page.

Comment: Why aren't you using [{% url ... %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) builtin in your template?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I'm only beginning to use Django.

Comment: No problem! Dont forget to take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `#anchor` to your link's `href`. In your case there will be different anchors (`<a name="comment_123"></a>`, for example) for all your comments, so be sure link points to correct anchor.

This is nothing to do with Django, just old good HTML.

Comment: When the HttpResponse object gets returned, the anchor is lost and hence the question. Say I was doing `return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog-post/%s#comment-%s' % (blog_post.id, post_comment.id))` your answer would be correct.

Comment: Seems I got your idea - your `useful-comment` is doing something, ok. Then it should not display anything, but return a redirect, and you can exactly as you said. You should always separate your views: ones that display data and ones that somehow update data. Also, good practice is to make updates on POST requests (in your case it will be POSTable form with button instead of a hyperlink), oherwise you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: I agree with you. As I read more of the tutorial yesterday I realized I'm not doing this the way it should be done. Thanks for the suggestions.